# sql average of a sum divided by a count

Tags: sql, count, sum, average

I am trying to do an SQL query to get the average spend for a specific customer.

I have written the following SQL (this is slighlty cut down for this example)..

```
SELECT SUM(price) as sumPrice, COUNT(transactionId) as transactionCount, customerName
FROM customers, transactions
WHERE customers.customerId = transactions.customerId
AND transactiontypeId = 1
GROUP BY customers.customerId
```

This gives me the sum of the transaction and the count. With this I can then divide the sum by the count to get the average spend. However I would like to be able to get the Average as a value straight out of the database rather than manipulate the data once I have got it out.

Is there any way to do this? I have played around with writing a select within a select but haven;t had much luck as of yet, hence asking on here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: sorry, I have a group by on the end of this query.. I'll update it

Comment: still wouldn't parse in most other RDBMS since you are `GROUPING BY` a different field than what is in the `SELECT` list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL has a mean average function built-in.

```
SELECT AVG(price) AS averageSpend, customerName
FROM customers, transactions
WHERE customers.customerId = transactions.customerId
AND transactiontypeId = 1
GROUP BY customers.customerId
```

Comment: so this would work out the average on the number of rows(transactions) associated to the customer?

Comment: `AVG(price)` will give you the same result (add them up, divide by count) as `SUM(price) / COUNT(transactions)` because the count used by `AVG()` is the total number of returned rows.

Comment: Hehe, don't feel stupid. Sometimes a problem just needs a fresh pair of eyes.

Comment: @Polynomial AVG excludes null values from its calculation. Therefore it is not the same as SUM divided by COUNT without additional where clauses.